# Laravel 5 fill method is not getting all attributes

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting data from a blade form using laravel 5.6 framework, When I get to the summary page the page is displaying only the last name attribute. Checking that step of my form with the dump and die function shows that my $meetings is only storing lastName but none of the other attributes.

I have checked my naming convenstions as well as changed the model from protected $guarded =[]; to protected $fillable =[val1, etc];

```
create-step1.blade.php:
<div class="row">
            <label>First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" value="{{{ $meetings->firstName or '' }}}" 
class="form-control" id="_firstName" name="firstName"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" value="{{{$meetings->lastName or ''}}}" 
class="form-control" id="_lastName" name="lastName"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" value="{{{$meetings->email or ''}}}" 
class="form-control" id="_email" name="email_address"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" value="{{{$meetings->phoneNum or ''}}}" 
class="form-control" id="_phoneNum" name="phone_number"/>
        </div>
    </div>

meetingsController.php code:
public function postCreateStep1(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'firstName'=> 'required|min:3',
        'lastName'=> 'required|min:3',
        'email_address'=>'required|email',
        'phone_number'=>'required|min:10',
    ]);

    if(empty($request->session()->get('meetings'))){
        $meetings = new Meetings();
        $meetings->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('meetings', $meetings);
    }else{
        $meetings = $request->session()->get('meetings');
        $meetings->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('meetings', $meetings);
    }
    dd($meetings);
    return redirect('/meetings/create-step2');
}

meetings.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Meetings extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =[
      'firtName',
      'lastName',
      'email',
      'phoneNum',
      'meetingType',
      'location',
      'datetime',
       ];
       //protected $table = "meetings";
 }


Meetings {#163 ▼
#fillable: array:7 [▼
0 => "firtName"
1 => "lastName"
2 => "email"
3 => "phoneNum"
4 => "meetingType"
5 => "location"
6 => "datetime"
]
#connection: null
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: false
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:1 [▼
"lastName" => "Lord"
]
#original: []
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, could you dd the validated data, so we could see if you are not loosing data after validation?

Comment: array:4 [▼
  "firstName" => "Daniel"
  "lastName" => "Lord"
  "email_address" => "daniellord32@dev.com"
  "phone_number" => "1234567890"
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you the input names in your firm values are not the exact same as your Meeting class attributes:

```
$form->first name !== $meeting->firtName
$form->email_address !== $meeting->email
$form->phone_number !== $meeting->phoneNum
```

Only `lastName` is the same on both which is why it fills as you expect. If you are going to use `->fill()` your form names have to match the Meeting attributes.